# Define a sequence $b_{0},b_{1}, b_{2},.... \in R$ recursively by $b_{0} = 0$ and $b_{n+1}=(b_{n})^2+ \frac{1}{4}$....

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Define a sequence $b_{0},b_{1}, b_{2},.... \in R$ recursively by $b_{0} = 0$ and $b_{n+1}=(b_{n})^2+ \frac{1}{4}$.Prove that, for all $n \leq 1$, $0 < b_{n} <1.$

I'm not sure how to approach this question, I've tried to use proof by induction, but I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: It might be easier to prove (by induction) that $0 < b_n < \tfrac{1}{2}$ for all integers $n \ge 1$.

You already know that $0 < b_1 = \tfrac{1}{4} < \tfrac{1}{2}$. Can you show that $0 < b_n < \tfrac{1}{2}$ implies $0 < b_{n+1} = b_n^2+\tfrac{1}{4} < \tfrac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Could you explain it please, i'm not sure how.